# Show product based on selected category in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The below code is a list of my categories (`product_categories`), list of products (`products`) and categories assigned to products (`product_selected_categories`).

I would like to display my product along with the category to which it was added.
I'm trying to do this using the following code:

```
Product::findOrFail($id)
```

But this code does not work. The code displays only the product without information about the category to which the product belongs.

How do I fix this?
My project is in Laravel 5.8.

1. Migration

```php
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 85)->nullable();
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->integer('level')->default(0);
            //$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->default(0);
            //$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('number')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            //$table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
            //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
            $table->smallInteger('id_delivery_vat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_delivery_vat')->references('id')->on('vat');
            $table->smallInteger('id_product_vat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_product_vat')->references('id')->on('vat');
            $table->bigInteger('id_producer')->unsigned();
            //$table->foreign('id_producer')->references('id')->on('product_producers');
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('qr_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('oe_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->char('promo', 1)->default(0);
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('product_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('promo_product_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('product_delivery_price', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('quantity')->default(0);
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });

Schema::create('product_selected_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory1_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory1_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory2_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory2_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory3_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory3_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory4_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory4_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory5_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory5_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory6_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory6_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory7_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory7_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory8_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory8_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('subcategory9_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_subcategory9_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
```

2. Models

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'id_delivery_vat', 'id_product_vat', 'id_producer', 'name', 'qr_code', 'oe_code', 'enable', 'promo', 'description', 'product_price', 'promo_product_price', 'product_delivery_price', 'quantity', 'url_address'];
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_selected_categories', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
}

class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'enable', 'name', 'url_address', 'level', 'parent_id', 'number'];
    public $timestamps = true;
    //protected $table = 'products_category';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCategory', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_selected_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}

class ProductSelectedCategory extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['subcategory1_id', 'parent_subcategory1_id', 'category_id', 'subcategory2_id', 'parent_subcategory2_id', 'subcategory3_id', 'parent_subcategory3_id', 'subcategory4_id', 'parent_subcategory4_id', 'subcategory5_id', 'parent_subcategory5_id', 'subcategory6_id', 'parent_subcategory6_id', 'subcategory7_id', 'parent_subcategory7_id', 'subcategory8_id', 'parent_subcategory8_id', 'subcategory9_id', 'parent_subcategory9_id', 'product_id' ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: If you're using a `many to many` relationship you should look around something called pivot tables :) check out this [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7quw05phxs&t=516s) (i'm not associated with its creator)

Comment: Hi, @goslscs – was my answer helpful to you? If so, please upvote & accept so that it can help someone else in the future. If not, I'm happy to try and help you reach a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ***know*** that you will need the Product's Categories, you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) related models by using the QueryBuilder's `with()` function:

```php
$product = Product::with('categories')->findOrFail($id);
```

If you have the need to eager load *multiple* relationships, you can pass an array to `with()`:

```php
$product = Product::with(['categories', ...])->findOrFail($id);
```

---

If, however, you ***may not*** need the Product's Categories, you can lazy load the categories with the `load()` function:

```php
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);

// ... some time later you end up needing the Categories...

$product->load('categories');
```

Here again, you may pass an array to `load()` if needed:

```php
$product->load(['categories', ...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option apart from those listed above would be to define a `$with` property on your `Product` model:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
  use scopeActiveTrait;

  protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'id_delivery_vat', 'id_product_vat', 'id_producer', 'name', 'qr_code', 'oe_code', 'enable', 'promo', 'description', 'product_price', 'promo_product_price', 'product_delivery_price', 'quantity', 'url_address'];
  protected $quarded = ['id'];
  public $timestamps = true;

  protected $with = ['categories'];
  ...
}
```

This is another way to use eager loading. It should only be used if you know that whenever you load a product (or products), you will ***always*** need every loaded product's categories. (see "Eager loading by default" [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading))

Answer (score -2):

You can load the relation in this way :

```
Product::findOrFail($id)->with('categories');
```